# How does XML transform work in Scala

Tags: xml, scala

I am looking for an application bug, which makes `scala.xml.BasicTransformer` run in infinite loop. First of all, I am reading [BasicTransformer.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala-xml/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/xml/transform/BasicTransformer.scala) to figure out how `transform` (see below) works:

```
abstract class BasicTransformer extends Function1[Node, Node] {

 // ...

  protected def unchanged(n: Node, ns: Seq[Node]) =
    ns.length == 1 && (ns.head == n)

  def transform(ns: Seq[Node]): Seq[Node] = {
    val (xs1, xs2) = ns span (n => unchanged(n, transform(n)))

    if (xs2.isEmpty) ns
    else xs1 ++ transform(xs2.head) ++ transform(xs2.tail)
  }

... // rest of the code

}
```

Could you explain

- why `transform` calls `span` with `unchanged`
- how it makes sure it *always* terminates with any `ns`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, span basically splits the Seq into two Seqs, where:

1. The first Seq contains elements that matches the filter function.
2. The second Seq *starts with* the first element that does not match the filter function.

A more technical explanation of `Seq#span(...)` can be found in the [API docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.Seq@span(p:A=%3EBoolean):(Repr,Repr)).

The transform function seems to simply be applying the transform recursively to all the nodes in the XML tree, and should always terminate.

After spanning the Seq of nodes, `xs1` contains elements where applying [`transform(n: Node)`](https://github.com/scala/scala-xml/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/xml/transform/BasicTransformer.scala#L41) (note that this is a different transform than the one you pasted) does not change n. `xs2` starts with the first element where applying transform to the element changes the element.

It is then done with `xs1`, but continues processing `xs2`: It applies `transform(n: Node)` to the first element of `xs2`, and `transform(ns: Seq[Node])` to the remaining elements in `xs2`.

The "`xs2`" keeps getting smaller and smaller until it's eventually empty, and the function terminates.

Edit:
I was thinking about this a little bit more, and I realize the span call isn't strictly necessary, it seems like they could have recursed and simply do a head::tail split, but I guess this implementation is more optimal? It does seem to call `transform(n: Node)` twice for each node that is not unchanged by the transform though.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. What if the `transform` (different than the one I pasted) _does_ change a node in _every_ invocation ? Does the `transform` I pasted terminate in that case too ?

Comment: Yup, it would still terminate. Basically, xs1 would always be empty. However, as you can see, xs2 (which would be == ns) is still split into its head and tail components, where `transform(n: Node)` (not the one you pasted) is called on the head, and `transform(ns: Seq[Node])` (the one you pasted) is applied to the tail. The transform you pasted will be called recursively, each time with a node Seq that is one smaller than the last call, until you eventually get an empty node Seq (in which case span will always return two empty Seqs, and the function terminates).

Comment: At least that's what it looks like to me. Are you running into a situation where it's not terminating?

Comment: Thanks again. I will think about it. I tried to transform an XML with a transformation rule, which changes a node in every invocation (e.g. adding an attribute with current time), and it _does_ terminate. I just did not understand why.

Comment: Yes, I believe I am running into a situation, which this `transform` (the one I pasted) runs in an endless loop.

Comment: I guess that since `transform(n: Node)` is called _twice_ for each node the overall complexity is exponential. Like in `T(n) = 2*T(n - 1)` recursion. Posted a new question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861880/is-complexity-of-scala-xml-ruletransformer-exponential